# how do I connect codeigniter to a SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, database, codeigniter, database-connection

I've seen a lot of posts but none that actually worked.  Can someone provide a clean/clear way to connect Codeigniter with a MS SQL Server on a Mac? This is high level but I have yet to see a solution that clearly demonstrates this.  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

I have already done this, in your `application/config/database.php` put the following:

```
// This address is valid if you're on the same domain as the server:
// If not, you can put the ip address or url here as well.
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'DBComputerName\SQLEXPRESS';

// if you need a non default port uncomment and edit
//$db['default']['port'] = '5432';

$db['default']['username'] = 'databaseUsername';
$db['default']['password'] = 'databasePassword';
$db['default']['database'] = 'DatabaseName';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

I know how frustrating this was, as a word of caution, not all Active Record functions work or work as expected, this is due to many SQL server quirks.

I recommend switching most of your Active Record queries to: `$this->db->query();`

**PS** If I remember correctly, MSSQL doesn't have a username preconfigured, you need to create a username and allow db access from outside of the subnet.

Refer to this in order to create the db user:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337545.aspx
and allow access:
http://support.webecs.com/KB/a868/how-do-i-configure-sql-server-express-to-allow-remote.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I use the PDO driver... this works for me:

```
    $db['mssql']['hostname'] = 'sqlsrv:server=myserverIP;database=mydb;encrypt=true;trustservercertificate=true';
    $db['mssql']['username'] = 'myun';
    $db['mssql']['password'] = 'mypw';
    $db['mssql']['database'] = 'mydb';
    $db['mssql']['dbdriver'] = 'pdo';
    $db['mssql']['dbprefix'] = '';
    $db['mssql']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
    $db['mssql']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
    $db['mssql']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
    $db['mssql']['cachedir'] = '';
    $db['mssql']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
    $db['mssql']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
    $db['mssql']['swap_pre'] = '';
    $db['mssql']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
    $db['mssql']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```